# PHP loop by assigning to every 3 items

Tags: php, loops

I want it to be in such

```
1 - Red
2 - Grey
3 - White

4 - Red
5 - Grey
6 - White

7 - Red
8 - Grey
9 - White
```

So basically the color red, grey, white will repeater every 3 time.
I try to use if ($row[0] % 3 == 0) but the 4th element will have problem.

here is the loop code.

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
                        {                         
if ($row[0] % 3 == 0) {

    echo 'id: '.$row[0].'<br>';                          
    echo 'i am white<br><br><br>';

} elseif ($row[0] % 2 == 0) {

    echo 'id: '.$row[0].'<br>';                          
    echo 'i am grey<br><br><br>';

} else {

    echo 'id: '.$row[0].'<br>';                          
    echo 'i am red<br><br><br>';
}
}
```

Comment: Show your loop code also.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you share your loop.

Comment: Question is unclear

Comment: i added the loop code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `modulo` (`%`) operation finds the remainder after division of one number by another.

So you have do something like:

```
while ( $row=mysqli_fetch_row($result) ) { 
    if ( $row[0] % 3 == 0 ) {                                    //Remainder is 0                                       
        echo 'id: '.$row[0].'<br>'; 
        echo 'i am white<br><br><br>'; 
    } elseif ( $row[0] % 3 == 1 ) {                              //Remainder is 1     
        echo 'id: '.$row[0].'<br>'; 
        echo 'i am grey<br><br><br>'; 
    } else {                                                     //Remainder is 2     
        echo 'id: '.$row[0].'<br>'; 
        echo 'i am red<br><br><br>'; 
    } /*$rowCount++; */ 
}
```

Comment: Yes @Eddie, let me try now and it seem to work perfectly.

Comment: Happy to help @GTS85